# Usage of "factual"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, adjective-phrases

From [Netflix to open London commissioning base](https://www.screendaily.com/news/netflix-to-open-london-commissioning-base/5130106.article):

> Broadcast understands that Diego Buñuel, who joined the business from Canal Plus in April, will head factual for the division.

Factual is an adjective, I think it is parsed as "factual for the division", but what does it mean "factual for something"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context is everything...

Netflix is a video streaming and tv production company.

They have something called "factual"... and it is headed by someone. In that context it must mean the "section that makes factual programmes". I.e. documentaries and reality programmes, in contrast to drama or comedy etc.

"Factual" is being used a noun here; it is short for "factual programme production" or something similar.